# Contact Like handling of fields

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, location, contacts

I am developing an App with information about a location. This information contains phone number, email address, address etc. A bit like the contact detail information of the iPhone itself.

Now my question. When I select a contact in my phonebook, I can select the phonenumber to call, select an emailaddress to mail and select the location information to view it in the maps of the iPhone. This is what I want to achieve.

I have searched google for this functionallity but I am probably searching for the wrong things.Can someone help me to achieve this functionallity?

Thanks!!!

**//// Followup**

Now I know that the stuff I want to add is possible, I have a followup question about this subject.

Does anyone know where I can find some examples about the actions for calling, mailing and location information? It would help me a lot...

Thnx!!

With kind regards,

Douwe

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/09/19/access-the-address-book/) for accessing address book details.

This example shows to display the first name, last name, instead you display phno.,email, location along with a button near ti it.

Then code in your button action to call, mail, view location respectively.

Comment: Thnx, I will look in to that!!! I keep this post open for any other suggestion!! Thanks again for your quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UITableView, then tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: will get sent to you (the table view delegate (usually the table view controller)) each time the user presses a row in your table.

In the Contacts app all phone numbers/emails/addresses for that contact are grouped in their own "section". By reading the section from the indexPath using [indexPath section] you will get the index for the section (a NSInteger).

Using your own app logic you can use that index to determine if the user pressed something in the phone/mail/address section. Now that you know what kind of information the user tapped on you can make the right thing (initiate a phone call/send an email/give directions)

Continuing using the same indexPath you can get the exact table view cell that the user clicked on by using [indexPath row]. Now you can send that information (say a phone number) to you own code to handle that information (initiate a phone call).

(Hope it helped, it was my first answer on StackOverflow)

Comment: Hi David! Thank you for your input!! A good answer!! Even for your first one :P Ha ha! But another question pops up! I will place within this question!